# iAd covers my view on the first load

Tags: ios, resize, ads, iad

I have iAds working almost perfectly using a modified version of [UITabBarController-iAds](https://github.com/jvashishtha/UITabBarController-iAds). The only issue I have is on the **very first** load of an advert my view gets covered. Once the ad refreshes after 30 seconds the view resizes just fine.

I'm using the following code:

```
- (void)layoutBanner 
{ 
    float height = 0.0; 
    ADBannerView *_banner = (ADBannerView *)[self.view viewWithTag:12]; 
    CGRect bounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds; 

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) { 
        _banner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait; 
    } else { 
        _banner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape; 
    } 

    //When compiling against iOS 8 SDK this needs to be height, regardless of the actual device orientation 
    height = bounds.size.height; 

    CGSize bannerSize = [ADBannerView sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier:_banner.currentContentSizeIdentifier]; 

    //Get content view 
    UIView *_contentView = self.selectedViewController.view; 

    CGRect contentFrame = _contentView.frame; 
    CGRect bannerFrame = _banner.frame; 

    if (_banner.isBannerLoaded) { 
        if (iOS7) { 
            contentFrame.size.height = height - bannerSize.height; 
            bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height; 
        } else { 
            contentFrame.size.height = height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height - bannerSize.height; 
            bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height; 
        } 
    } else { 
        if (iOS7) { 
            contentFrame.size.height = height; 
            bannerFrame.origin.y = bounds.size.height; 
        } else { 
            contentFrame.size.height = height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height; 
            bannerFrame.origin.y = bounds.size.height; 
        } 
    } 

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{ 
        _banner.frame = bannerFrame; 
        _contentView.frame = contentFrame; 
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_banner]; 
    }]; 
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner 
{ 
    NSLog(@"Did load"); 
    [self layoutBanner]; 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by playing around with the animation block. I moved the content view line and it resolved the issue

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
 _banner.frame = bannerFrame;
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     _contentView.frame = contentFrame;
     [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_banner];
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I suppose the problem is related to:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_banner];
```

The whole animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{ 
        _banner.frame = bannerFrame; 
        _contentView.frame = contentFrame; 
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_banner]; 
    }];
```

is a little strange, because at the completion block you are bringing the banner view to front, so I can suppose that before animation did start - the banner was covered by some other view or views - what is the reason of frame animation if banner view is covered - thus cannot be seen while animation is in progress?

Of course the issue applies only for the first run.

Comment: Hmm yeah I think I follow your logic there. The advert loads, then the layout is updated to specify where the advert you align and then it's animated to make the movement. Apple's implementation is slightly different so I might give that a try.

Comment: Try to add "[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_banner];" to the viewDidLoad method of the controller where the banner is implemented. Let me know about result.

Comment: I can't do that as the code I posted is in a category and not a ViewController.

Comment: I think you should change views hierarchy in the Interface Builder to get rid of call "bringSubviewToFront".

Comment: I appreciate the ideas Artur but the reason I am using this category is because of its simplicity. I add it to my project and add a couple of lines to get it working. Nothing done to my ViewControllers and nothing on the Storyboards. I'd prefer to preserver with it at this stage before giving up and trying a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. as of iOs8 [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds] has changed..  previously it would always return portrait (where H > W ) values, regardless of interfaceOrientation, but it now appears to respect interface orientation...  (which is not a bad thing, unless you're taking previous behaviour for granted)
2. Why don't you try CGRectGetMinY(CGRect aRect) ..

eg. (Im assuming from your code the banner goes along the screen bottom, and your TAbBar across the top. (which I think is weird..) )

```
    //once you have calculated bannerFrame

    contentFrame.size.height = ( CGRectGetMinY(bannerFrame)  - CGRectGetMinY (contentView.frame)  );

contentFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.tabbar.frame);
```

3. Do you have any constraints / resizingMasks set?  when you load a second ad the view controller's view has already been resized to fit an ad, presumably the first ad is the one trying to change things..

Comment: 1. Yep. 2. No, the tab bar as at the bottom and the ads are above them. 3. Can you elaborate?